# Symfony events - how to not trigger kernel events by Profiler or warmup

Tags: symfony, events, controller, profiler

Symfony v3.4 project, with several defined listeners/subscribers, for various purposes. They are hooked up to `kernel.request` and `kernel.controller` events.

I notice that all of them also get triggered by any requests made by Symfony's profiler tool, as well as in cases when Symfony is warming up the code cache.

Should it really be like that? 
Is there a nice way to NOT trigger the defined kernel.* events (specific ones at least), when a page request comes from Profiler? What would the best way to do it?

Regarding the excluding of those events on warm-up - I believe the warmup would be quicker if it wouldn't be doing all the hooking up etc, so it the development would be slightly quicker.

I saw an earlier, self-answered questions in here: [How to prevent Symfony profiler from accessing or executing a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360858/how-to-prevent-symfony-profiler-from-accessing-or-executing-a-listener), but that seems like too much work to do in my use case - changing all the existing controllers in the system.
Also, other offered comments/patches don't seem like a really good way to handle this. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: As far as the profiler is concerned, just looking for a [route named _wdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074428/symfony-4-ignore-kernel-events-coming-from-debug-toolbar/48097062#48097062) will work.  But you really need a good reason (performance is not a good reason) to do this.  If you don't want the profiler to run then disable it.  If you do then you want it to display correct information.

Comment: Tnx @Cerad, as always you make very good points. I wasn't considering the possible loss of actual information in the Profiler, although I could personally live with that - provided that I can quickly get them back when needed (so - easily allow the events again, for profiling purposes).  The thing is - not all developers on the system have the same needs, regarding profiler etc, but they all would like to have it running as quick as possible.  There are really some other reasons not related to speed, that I didn't mention here, but those would be really another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible as `WebProfilerBundle` relies to [symfony's event system](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php)

As profiler routes starts with `_` prefix, you can ignore it with:

```php
$route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
if (strpos($route, '_') === 0) {
    return;
}
```

```
  _twig_error_test              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  _wdt                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_phpinfo             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results      ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler_open_file           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                    
  _profiler                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
```

Comment: I do currently use something like this, but that doesn't prevent all the listeners from being instanced in the first place and any classes needed for them being injected.  So, besides what you suggested here, I also used the lazy-loading services (through `ServiceSubscribers`) to actually stop injecting stuff into the listeners when it's definitely not needed.